# Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have written a utility that monitors for Unhandled Exceptions and then creates a minidump in the event that one happens.

Is there a way, when the event triggers, rather than having the standard messagebox displaying the unhandled exception, could I disable that and display my own with different information?

Thanks.

Comment: are you after replacing MessageBox with your own dialog? Not sure what you ask here.

Comment: Hi,  Yes...when the user runs the program and an unhandled exception occurs, they get the standard unhandled exception messagebox.  I want to disable that messagebox.  When the unhandled exception occurs, I have an event that triggers, creates a minidump and I also want to display my own error message.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the `Application.ThreadException` event to show your own error messages.

You can hook the event at the top of your main method like this:

```
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

And then you need the Handler method:

```
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
}
```

Edit: You can also handle the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event because certain exceptions don't go through the `ThreadException` handler.

Comment: I am able to do that, what I want to do is disable the standard c# warning message.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 Could also be helpful to handle the Application.ThreadExit event.

Comment: It does disable that when you hook into the event. The current thread only has one exception handler, not a chain of them like normal events. When you hook in with your handler, they unhook their default handler, which shows the normal exception message.

Comment: @mike, what do you mean by hook into the handler?  I'm fairly new to C#.  I have the event setup and it is triggered (the undhandled exception event)  How do I then stop the messagebox showing the error?  Thanks

Comment: @Mike, thanks for your efforts, but they don't seem to work for me.  The code is within a dll file, when an unhandled exception occurs in any given program the unhandledException event is triggered and handled and the dump created.  When i add the messagebox code to the handler method, I still get the standard error message.  Thanks again - much appreciated.

Comment: Are the exceptions being thrown on a different thread than the main thread? The `ThreadException` event only applies to the thread on which you hook it. Also, did you try the AppDomain.UnhandledException event?

Comment: The AppDomain.UnhandledException event is the one that I am using.  When the unhandled exception occurs, I have MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString()); as you have written earlier, that shows up, but the standard one shows as well.  I am only using one thread at present, i'm using a very small test bed to get this to work.  Thanks.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that if you are running with a debugger attached, it may be preventing the exceptions from being routed through the `ThreadException` handler since VS has to display them. Try running without a debugger attached to see if the default error message still appears.

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing it, you can do whatever you want with it. Show it on MessageBox or write it to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that ,

```
catch(Exception e)
{
throw new Exception("This is unhandled exception");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223898.aspx).